# Insert Data in to ms access C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to insert data from a form to msaccess database i have the current code

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\kunz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Assignment_2_Mark_2\App_Data\nuclearpopsicledb.mdb";
cmd.Connection = con;
string sql = "insert into users values('"+tbUname.Text+"','"+tbPass.Text+"','"+tbName.Text+"','"+tbEmail.Text+"','"+tbEmail.Text+"')";

try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Label1.Text = "TRY";
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
    con.Close();
}
```

my data base is structured like:

**|username | password | name | email |**

but when ever i run it i get an error like

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Number of query values and
>   destination fields are not the same. at System.Data.

i am not sure what i am doing wrong i am a beginner in C#

Comment: Your objects that implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) such as `OleDbConnection` are not being handled properly. Wrap them in a using statement.

Comment: I understand this is probably a learning assignment, but you are storing plaintext passwords in the database. This is a big security violation. Passwords should be one way hashed and encrypted, never stored in plaintext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra email you are passing:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", tbUname.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", tbPass.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", tbName.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", tbEmail.Text.Trim());

string sql = 
    "insert into users " +
    "values(@userName, @password, @Name, @Email)";
```

Comment: is this the best way to do it 
is there a better way like to prevent sql injections

Comment: @GibralterTop Then show how to do parameters. Don't show how to do things the incorrect way.

Comment: Parameters are great for preventing sql injection. But you also need to hash that pass.

Comment: Else you or some malicious user might feel a little curious one day and try out some email password combinations on `facebook`, `amazon`, `bank of america`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Actually your table contains four values, but you are passing 5 values in that query. That is the mistake.

Your Code:

```
string sql = "insert into users values('"+tbUname.Text+"','"+tbPass.Text+"','"+tbName.Text+"','"+tbEmail.Text+"','"+tbEmail.Text+"')";
```

`tbEmail.Text` is repeating Twice.